# Showing that, if $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, then $\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}$ tends to $\sqrt{2}-1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Show that, for the recurrence $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2},$$ the ratio $\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}$ tends to $\sqrt{2}-1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Not sure about this one, I know the recurrence relation solution is $$a_n=\frac{1}{2}\left((1-\sqrt{2})^n+(1+\sqrt{2})^n\right)$$ but not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: How do you know $a_n=\frac{1}{2}\Big((1-\sqrt{2})^n+(1+\sqrt{2})^n\Big)$?  Perhaps you know $a_0$ and $a_1$?  Otherwise you know $a_n=c(1-\sqrt{2})^n+d(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ for some $c$ and $d$, which so long as $d\not=1$ should lead to the ratio tending towards .$(1+\sqrt{2})$

Comment: So if $a_0=a_1=1$ then you get the sequence $1,1,3,7,17,\ldots$ with the ratio tending towards $1+\sqrt{2}$, while if $a_0=1,a_1=1-\sqrt{2}$ you get the sequence $1, 1-\sqrt{2},3-\sqrt{8},7-\sqrt{50}, 17-\sqrt{288}, \ldots$ with the ratio tending towards $1-\sqrt{2}$, neither of which are your $\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: and my initial comment should have said "so long as $d \not = 0$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2}\big((1-\sqrt{2})^n+(1+\sqrt{2})^n\big),
$$
then you can directly calculate that
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{(1-\sqrt{2})^n+(1+\sqrt{2})^n}{(1-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}+(1+\sqrt{2})^{n-1}};
$$
multiplying numerator and denominator by $(1+\sqrt{2})^{-n}$ (the reciprocal of the biggest term in sight) yields
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{(1-\sqrt{2})^n(1+\sqrt{2})^{-n}+1}{(1-\sqrt{2})^{n-1}(1+\sqrt{2})^{-n}+(1+\sqrt{2})^{-1}}.
$$
Can you find the limit of this expression as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that $a_0, a_1 > 0$.

Let $b_n=a_n/a_{n-1}$. You have $b_n=2+1/b_{n-1}$. Noting $x$ the limit of $b_n$ you get $x=2+1/x$. Can you conclude from here ?

By the way, the limit is $1+\sqrt{2}$ and not $\sqrt{2}-1$.

**EDIT:** The fact that $b_n$ admits a limit is immediate since $(b_n)$ is bounded in $[2,2.5]$ from rank $3$, with a unique accumulation point.

Comment: This is true, as long as you first show that the limit exists (and so you can use limit arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=1+\sqrt 2$ and $s=\sqrt 2-1$. Then $\frac {a_n} {a_{n-1}}=\frac {t^{n}+s^{n}} {t^{n-1}+s^{n-1}}=\frac {t^{n}(1+u^{n})}  {t^{n-1}(1+u^{n-1})} $ where $u=\frac  s t$. Since $0<u <1$ we get $u^{n} \to 0$. Hence the limit is $t=1+\sqrt 2$.